# Display data in dynamic columns

Tags: postgresql

I have data like this in the postgres db column with two rows named Data_Column,

[image: sample data data]

I would like to display the data like this,The colon left hand side is the column name and the colon right hand side is the column value.

[image: Output Format required]

I have tried crosstab function ,but it is not working for me.Can u help on this.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using `substring()` with a regular expression:

```
select substring(data_column from 'data_as_of_date:([0-9]+)') as data_as_of_date,
       substring(data_column from 'unique_cc:([0-9]+)') as unique_cc
from the_table;
```

Comment: Can we make this columns dynamical without hard coding.Is it possible?